# Show value in template in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have some code below, I want show "header" in template and show or hide when header not null.

```
<div id="hung">
    <cmx-test v-bind:header="${properties.header}"></cmx-test>
</div>
<script>
Vue.component('cmx-test', {
    props: ['header'],
        template: '<h1 class=\"fillColor\" data={{this.header}}></h1>'
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#hung'
});

</script>
```

Comment: you would know if you spend some effort to study Vue documentation.

Comment: How is this related to AEM?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear.  You have the component receiving the prop `header` but `header` is not defined on the main Vue instance.  You need to be passing that prop from the main data object / Vue instance into the component to use it there.

```
<div id="hung">
    <cmx-test v-if="header" :header="header"></cmx-test>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('cmx-test', {
        props: ['header'],
           template: '<h1 class=\"fillColor\" :data="header">{{header}}</h1>'
    });

    // create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#hung'
      data:{
         header: null,
      }
    });
</script>
```

Also using the same data object `header` to control whether the component is rendered or not using `v-if`. So if `header` is null or false it wont be rendered.  When it becomes true or contains a value it will be rendered and the value of `header` will be passed to component through binding it (e.g. :header="header")

Comment: the problem is data={{this.header}} not working. If i use <h1>{{header}}</h1> Everything is ok

Comment: Sorry I copied and pasted your code and over looked that. See my edited code above. You don't use mustache braces in html element tags like that.  You need to bind that value using shorthand `:data="header"` or  `v-bind:data="header"`.  This binds the value of header to the `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax mistake in your code, to insert text into tag you can achieve with `v-text` attribute not `data={{this.header}}`.

And if you wanna hide some tag or component based on data value, you can use `v-if`.

And the last thing is if you wanna pass value intro component you can achieve that with this way `v-bind:header="value"`, and `value` is variable which hold value you wanna pass.

```
<div id="hung">
    <cmx-test v-if="header" v-bind:header="value"></cmx-test>
    <button @click="header = true">Display</button>
</div>
<script>
Vue.component('cmx-test', {
    props: ['header'],
    template: '<h1 class=\"fillColor\" v-text="header"></h1>'
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#hung',
  data: {
    header: null,
    value: "Hello World!"
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah good point.  I missed that he was not trying to create a 'data` attribute but trying to pass the header text into the element.